# Starting firefox-selenium macos

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to start selenium with Firefox with python but if I understand the Error message correctly it can't find the file. I've tried to find an answer to this, but every "answer" I find is on another operating system and doesn't have to do with my problem. 
I have Firefox installed and Selenium.

In the shell I enter:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

and it returns:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
>       stdin=PIPE)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 707, in **init**
>       restore_signals, start_new_session)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
>       raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg)
>   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'geckodriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       browser = webdriver.Firefox()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 152, in **init**
>       self.service.start()
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
>       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)